# Removing the name provided by website

Tags: discussion, display-names

How to get rid of the name or you can just see my name is user2060755. So how to set my original name?

Comment: Go to your profile. Click on the edit link to the right. And then change your display name.

Answer (score 4):

You need to navigate to [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/210891/user2060755). Then you need to edit your profile (edit button in the top middle right). You can change your username there, and then save your changed name. You can only do this once every 30 days.

In fact, I made a typo making my name and have to wait 10 more days to fix it.

Comment: The username can be changed freely within (several 2-3?) days since registration. After that, the user name can be changed once every 30 days, but there is a grace period of (15?) minutes that you can change your username to fix typo.